# Client Priviledge for hard drive

Tags: windows-10

I have attached a screen shot of the notification I received after trying generate a simple txt file in the home directory of my hard drive, why in this case it refers to a "client" where as all other cases have referred to  "permissions" granted to users that are "Administrators" or "Owners"?

What is the difference between a privilege and a permission?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to know how to solve the problem or to talk about the nuances of different terminology people use?

Comment: The dialog message is different because it’s custom to the application itself

Comment: @Appleoddity um no I am posting a question because I have done the standard things ie add my username and give it full control, I get the same error message regardless of whether i have read write permission

Comment: probably go with saving my money and buying the Linux version of the CAS i have been using on windows for the past decade i mean that's literally  the only thing it has going for it, the fact that i haven't yet been able to pirate the Linux download of the CAS i use

Comment: Then again, I ask, is your request about how to solve this problem? Or, is it about the nuances of terminology? One can be answered, the other is opinion based. Please clarify your post.

Comment: yes i am still stuck with windows so how do i get full access to my computers hard drive what part about that is unclear to you?

Comment: @Adam The part that tells us what application you are using ... and why are you trying to save into the root of drive C:? That is brain dead. You should be saving to you home directory.

Comment: @Adam So have you paid for the Windows copy or is that pirated? We do not help with pirated software.